# javascript reduce function sum of all array values

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, sum

```
   for (var j = 0; j < l; j++) {
      aa = (j*5)/12/100;

      const arr = [ { x: aa } ];
      const result = arr.reduce( ( sum, { x } ) => sum + x , 0);
      console.log( result );

    }
```

I have tried to sum of all output numbers using javascript reduce. But, counldn't able to achieve the desired output. This `aa` variable returns 5 for first 12 counts and then returns 10 for next 12 counts. So, I want this line `console.log(result)` should return *180* ((5*12)+(10*12)). But, it returns 5 and 10 in console.

Comment: I think that's a misunderstanding of reduce, or arrays in common (or variable declaration), in the first place. You are constantly overriding result (and everything else), and the sum of an array with only one value will always be equal to a single value.

Comment: also your calculations are wrong; js will do the division properly, you will get real numbers, not integers; the first `aa` value will be zero, the second 0.004166.., the third 0.00833.. and so on

Comment: also-also, which js version are you using? afaik you either should use `var` to declare values or `let/const`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to do it like this, then you should try:

```js
const arr = [];
for (var j = 0; j < 10; j++) {
  let aa = (j*5)/12/100;
  arr.push({ x: aa });
}
const result = arr.reduce( ( sum, { x } ) => sum + x , 0);
console.log( result );
```

else you're re-declaring `result` and `arr` at every iteration.

Comment: It returns NaN.

Comment: @KaruppiahRK what is l? It returns a number for me every time I try. Check the snippet and replace with `l`.

Comment: But, Now it returns 60 (5*12) and 120 (10*12) in separate line. It doesn't count these two values. It should be 180

Comment: Can you please show me your code again? I don't see how you get two `console.logs` with only one present.

Comment: Sorry. That's my mistake. I have multiple for loops. For loop inside for loop. I solved it.